# Check if number has its digits in order

Tags: sorting, haskell, int, digits

I am trying to check if, given any number, its digits are in order. Example:

1479 -> TRUE

1293 -> FALSE

Is there a proper way to do this in Haskell? I am new to the language and feel really lost at the moment. Thank you.

Comment: Well it looks like you do this in two steps (a) obtain the individual digits, and (b) check if these are ordered.

Comment: I have found out a way to do the first step: `digits:: Integral x => x -> [x]
digits 0 = []
digits x = listaDigitos (x div 10) ++ [x mod 10].` Any clues on the second one? Thanks.

Comment: use `zip` to get every two consecutive digits, and then check if for `all` items it holds that `digit <= nxt_digit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is this:

```
ordenado n
   | mod n 10 > mod (div n 10) 10 = ordenado (div n 10)
   | n == 0 = True
   | otherwise = False
```

Answer (score 6):

I think @vps approach is proper enough but just for some variety you may also do the job as follows;

```
Prelude> and $ zipWith (<) <*> tail $ show 1479
True
Prelude> and $ zipWith (<) <*> tail $ show 1293
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into String and use simple recursion and pattern matching.

```
   checkInOrder :: Int -> Bool
   checkInOrder x = isInOrder $ show x

   isInOrder :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool    
   isInOrder [] = True
   isInOrder [x] = True
   isInOrder (x:y:xs) = (x < y) && (isInOrder (y:xs))

   main = print (checkInOrder 1234)
```